# npm error while installing package in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, nvm, npm-package

When I try to install any npm package, I get the following error. And the installation gets stuck.

I've pasted the error below

**Error msg:**

***This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!***

[image: Error screenshot]

Help me to solve this problem. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you mentioned is due to the fact that you are running an older version of `npm`. You are probably on v5 or v6 while your `package-lock.json` was generated with v7+.

However, that message is usually a warning, and not a final error. Would double check to see if you have other error messages as well.

More details for `package-lock.json` versions at: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-lock-json#lockfileversion

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ivn_bogdan Now how can I get rid of that error?

Comment: try updating your npm version: https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm

Comment: Even though I use the node 16.15.0 version I'm getting an error as Unexpected Token '.' @0xBobby